# Use stored credentials in Python Amazon Simple Product API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I would like to use the credentials stored in ~/.amazon-product-api to make requests. The simple-product-api tells me to do it like this:

```
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI
amazon = AmazonAPI(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG)
```

But I don't want to put my credentials in the code. Unfortunately python-amazon-product-api doesn't support Python3 yet, otherwise I could have done what is suggested on this page: https://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic-usage.html

Does anyone have a way to use the stored credentials, or a way to not include the credentials in the code?

Comment: Put your AWS credentials in an INI/JSON file, give te file the appropriate permissions, and create a function in your code to read from the INI/JSON file. And/or, read the values from the shell/command line.

Answer (score 0):

python-amazon-product-api is tested on Python 3.5.